# SSL protocol is able to provide protection against SYN Flooding attack?

Tags: security, ssl, https, ddos, syn

I was wondering if SSL protocol is able to provide any way to protect the users from a SYN Flooding (Ddos) attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SYN Flooding as you know is ddos attack. The attacker send SYN packet to "flooding" server and make consuming server resources. Server is busy so anyone can't connect establish successful TCP handshake.

SSL is protocol what protect us from capture important data (like password). SSL or the newest version TSL don't protect us from ddos.

Anyway SSL is old protocol and you should use TSL 1.2 or 1.3(more safe).

DDoS attacks is like... send 1 million request about this same server in this same time and next this server don't have time to responsible to this request.

I think wikipedia in this topic can you help understand this problem.

Example:

You have server what can connect with 10 different user in this time, but the attacker use 100 PC to connect with your server. So the attacker send 100 packet SYN. Next your server want resent 100 SYN-ACK packet to this 100 PC, but on 1 s server can only get 10 SYN and resend 10 SYN-ACK.

SSL work that:

```
You -> SYN -> Server
You <- SYN-ACK <- Server
You -> ACK -> Server
etc.
```

As you see the attacker also can send SYN to server like you, but don't resend respond and make spam of packet SYN. SSL don't have anything what can't block DDoS.

Answer (score 3):

SYN attacks try to exhaust a system so that no successful TCP handshakes can be done. But the SSL/TLS protocol starts only **after** a successful TCP handshake, i.e. it requires a successful TCP handshake first.  Therefore SSL/TLS does not help against SYN flooding.